# preventing google from indexing/caching

Tags: indexing, http-headers, privacy

is there a **reliable** way to prevent google from crawling/indexing/caching a page?

i am thinking about creating a product where users could temporarily share information, using temporary url's.

the information is not very confidential, but i'd definitely like to not see it show up on some cache or even search results.

what's the most reliable way of doing this, and what are the possible pitfalls?

Answer (score 2):

Make a robots.txt file. See http://www.robotstxt.org/ for information.

You can also use `<META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW">` in the `<HEAD>` of your index.html.

Google's specifications for their robots.txt handling are [here](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/control-crawl-index/docs/robots_txt).

Comment: thanks. i am just wondering how realistic it is to expect to have this file, and have it work in the way i described in my question. do you have any experience with using it?

Comment: It is very standard, and the only agent I've seen ignore it is Baidu (which I have since forcibly blocked via iptables).